# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SignupComponent: ([object Object], ?). at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)

Tags: javascript, angular

Please help me to solve this problem.

### signup.component.html

```
<main role="main" class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">&nbsp;</h1>
    <h5 class="mt-5">Create Account</h5>
    <br/>
    <div class="loader" *ngIf="dataLoading"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="error">
        An error occured. Here is the error {{errorMessage}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="savedChanges else showForm">
        New Account is created. Please login.
        <button class="btn btn-log btn-primary btn-block" routerLink="/login">Login</button> 
    </div>
    <ng-template #showForm>
        <span class="lead">
            <form class="formsignin" #newUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="setUser(newUserForm.value)">
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" name=inputEmail id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" #inputEmail="ngModel" autofocus required email ngModel >
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="inputEmail.invalid && (inputEmail.dirty || inputEmail.touched)">
                    Please enter a valid email.
                </div>
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="password" name=inputPassword id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" #inputPassword="ngModel" autofocus required minlength="3" maxlength="15" ngModel >
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="inputPassword.invalid && (inputPassword.dirty || inputPassword.touched)">
                    Please enter a valid password.
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div *ngIf="!newUserForm.valid else showSubmitButton">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-block" type="submit" disabled>Sign up</button>
                </div>
                <ng-template>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
                </ng-template>
                <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">
                   <a routerLink="/login">Login</a> 
                </p>
            </form>
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</main>
```

In html form i am just writing a only two input fields email and password and take it some validations that's it.

### signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendService } from '../services/backend.service';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  error:boolean = false;
  errorMessage:String = "";
  dataLoading:boolean = false;
  private querySubscription;
  saveChanges:boolean = false;

  constructor(private _backendService:BackendService, private _route:Route) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setUser(formData){
    this.dataLoading = true;
    this.querySubscription = this._backendService.setUser(formData).subscribe(
      (res)=>{
        if(res["errorCode"]>0){
          this.error = false;
          this.errorMessage = "";
          this.dataLoading = false;
          this.saveChanges = true;

        }else{
          this.error = true;
          this.errorMessage = res["errorMessage"];
          this.dataLoading = false;
        }
      },
      (error)=>{
        this.error = true;
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
        this.dataLoading = false;
      },
      ()=>{
        this.dataLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.querySubscription){
      this.querySubscription.unsbscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

In signup.component.ts file i am just checking the input field are validate or not if yes then go to the next procedure.

### backend.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {

  constructor() { }

  setUser(formData){
    let fakeResponse = {
      "errorCode" : 1,
      "errorMessage" : "User Created",
      "rowCount" : 30,
      "data":{
        "taken" : "abcd"
      }
    };

    let fakeResponse_1 = {
      "errorCode" : 0,
      "errorMessage" : "Some error",
      "rowCount" : 30,
      "data":{
        "taken" : "abcd"
      }
    };

    return Observable.create(
      observer =>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
          observer.next(fakeResponse_1)
        }
          ,2000)});
  }
}
```

In service file checking the user data and return the some output.

I am just creating a simple login form using some validations but i got some errors.
I don't know what happens there,
please help me to solve this error.

Comment: I suspect the import for `Route`, it should be imported from `@angular/router` instead of `@angular/compiler/src/core`. Secondly, why you even want to inject the Route if you are not using on the page

Comment: Problem solved...                                                                                                  (private _route:Route) and importing the   @angular/compiler/src/core;                                                                                                    Correct statement is                                                                                                                             (private _route:Router) and importing the  '@angular/router';                                               Thanks  @SumitKale your comment help me to solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Rushikesh Gadekar,
Your Problem is that Angular doesn't provide your backend-service for the constructor of your signup-component.
To solve this Problem you have to go to:
**app.module.ts**

And insert your Service to your providors.

Here's an Example how this could look like.

```js
import { MyDataService } from './service/my-data/my-data.service';
import { ControlService } from './service/control/control.service';
import { ViewListService } from './service/view-list/view-list.service';
import { DevDataService } from './service/dev-data/dev-data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
  providers: [
    ControlService,
    MyDataService,
    ViewListService,
    DevDataService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```